# Seeking Guidance on Extracting Point Cloud and Facial Measurements from Object Capture Scans

Tags: ios, realitykit, lidar, facial-landmark-alignment

I am currently working with Object Capture and would appreciate some guidance on extracting specific data from the scans. I have successfully scanned objects, but I am now looking to obtain the point cloud and facial measurements from these scans.

I have used https://developer.apple.com/documentation/RealityKit/guided-capture-sample as a reference for implementation.

**Point Cloud:**

How can I extract the point cloud data from my Object Capture scans? Are there any specific tools or methods recommended for this purpose?

**Facial Measurements:**

Is there a way to extract facial measurements accurately using Object Capture? Are there any built-in features or third-party tools that can assist with this? I've explored the documentation, but I would greatly benefit from any insights, tips, or recommended workflows from the community. Your expertise is highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.